# Chart.js loading data colors from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am trying to load a chart with activity data from a database using json_encode, it works fine for labels and data values, but not for the background color.

I can do

```js
var myColors = < ?php echo json_encode($myColors); ?>;
```

and then in the chart do

```js
backgroundColor: [myColors[0], myColors[1]]
```

just fine, but I can't just do

```js
backgroundColor: myColors
```

Also doing

```js
var myColors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
```

and then

```js
backgroundColor: myColors
```

will work just fine, I just can't get it to do that with the PHP array.

```js
//var myColors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
var myColors = <?php echo json_encode($myColors); ?>;

//All chart data
var data = {
    labels: <?php echo json_encode($activityNames); ?>, //Get activity names from PHP array
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Daily Activities',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($activityTimes); ?>, //Get times from PHP array
        backgroundColor: [myColors[0], myColors[1], myColors[2], myColors[3], myColors[4], myColors[5], myColors[6]],
        borderColor: '#333',
        borderWidth: 4
    }]
};
```

The way the code is now works fine, but if I want to add an extra data piece in the database then I will also have to update this code to include myColors[7], or delete myColors[6] if I remove a piece of data. Also having backgroundColor: myColors will make the chart all gray and tooltips won't work

Comment: How do you define the PHP `$myColors` variable? View your page source (the actual source, not the element inspector, eg `Ctrl+U`). What does the JS actually look like?

Comment: Make another test.php, and that contains only `< ?php echo json_encode($myColors); ?>`. And, you can check what is generated with this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of for this not to work is if your PHP `$myColors` variable is either an object or a non-continuous array (ie you have skipped keys).

The former is unlikely so assuming the latter, eg

```php
$myColors = [0 => 'red', 1 => 'blue', 3 => 'green'];
```

You would get a JS object like

```js
{"0":"red","1":"blue","3":"green"}
```

The solution is to create an array with sequential keys. If you're building one up, don't directly assign index values, use

```php
$myColors[] = 'blue'
```

instead to push new values.

If this cannot be avoided, use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-values.php) to create an indexed array

```js
var myColors = <?= json_encode(array_values($myColors)) ?>;
```

Comment: Using array_values() worked, but it showed the colors in an odd order, which led me down the path of realizing that I had an error in my array initialization, so there were skipped keys in the array. Thanks!